# OpenCV calibrateCamera() returns too high reprojection error (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried to calibrate Iphone 11 Pro camera and openCV calibrateCamera() function returns error more than 1.2+ (same for computeReprojectionErrors() below). I want them to be lower than 0.5, because after this I am making disparity map and I need it to be smooth. How can I minimize it? Here is my code and I made 90 pictures of board from diffirent angles which are stored in ../chess_image. Here is code: github.com/markilebyak/opencv.git

Also here: 4shared.com/folder/PSDaeTcI/opencv.html are 36 images from those 90 I used, and 34 grayscaled with detected lines from those 36.

```
void createKnownBoardPosition(Size &boardSize, float squareEdgeLength, vector<Point3f>& corners) {
    for (int i = 0; i < boardSize.height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < boardSize.width; j++) {
            corners.emplace_back((float)j * squareEdgeLength, (float)i * squareEdgeLength, 0.0f);
        }
    }
}



void process_images(std::string &path_to_directory, Size &chessboard_size, vector<vector<Point2f>>& allFoundCorners) {
//    Function to iterate through images
//    taken for camera calibration
    vector<String> filenames;
    cv::glob(path_to_directory, filenames);
    vector<Point2f> pointBuffer;
    int counter = 0;
    for (const auto & filename : filenames) {
        if (filename != "../chess_images/.DS_Store"){
            Mat im = imread(filename);
            std::cout << filename << std::endl;
            Mat gray_im;
            cvtColor(im, gray_im, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            bool found = findChessboardCorners(gray_im, chessboard_size, pointBuffer,
                                               CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);
            if (found) {
                counter++;
                TermCriteria criteria = TermCriteria( TermCriteria::EPS + TermCriteria::MAX_ITER,
                        30,0.0001 );
                Size winSize = Size( 11, 11);
                Size zeroZone = Size( -1, -1 );
                //cornerSubPix is the algorithm focused on relocating the points. it receives the image, the corners
                // a window size, zeroZone and the actual criteria. The window size is the search area.
                cornerSubPix(gray_im, pointBuffer, winSize, zeroZone, criteria );
                drawChessboardCorners( gray_im, chessboard_size, Mat(pointBuffer), found );
                string nametext = "../drawn_chessboard/" + to_string(counter) + ".jpg";
                imwrite(nametext, gray_im);
                allFoundCorners.push_back(pointBuffer);
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Images used: " << counter << std::endl;
}


double computeReprojectionErrors( const vector<vector<Point3f> >& objectPoints,
                                         const vector<vector<Point2f> >& imagePoints,
                                         const vector<Mat>& rvecs, const vector<Mat>& tvecs,
                                         const Mat& cameraMatrix , const Mat& distCoeffs,
                                         vector<float>& perViewErrors, bool fisheye) {
    vector<Point2f> imagePoints2;
    size_t totalPoints = 0;
    double totalErr = 0, err;
    perViewErrors.resize(objectPoints.size());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < objectPoints.size(); ++i )
    {
        if (fisheye)
        {
            fisheye::projectPoints(objectPoints[i], imagePoints2, rvecs[i], tvecs[i], cameraMatrix,
                                   distCoeffs);
        }
        else
        {
            projectPoints(objectPoints[i], rvecs[i], tvecs[i], cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, imagePoints2);
        }
        err = norm(imagePoints[i], imagePoints2, NORM_L2);
        size_t n = objectPoints[i].size();
        perViewErrors[i] = (float) std::sqrt(err*err/n);
        totalErr        += err*err;
        totalPoints     += n;
    }
    return std::sqrt(totalErr/totalPoints);
}


void calibration_process(Size &boardSize, float &squareEdgeLength, Mat& cameraMatrix, Mat& distortionCoefficients,
                         std::string &path_to_directory) {

    vector<vector<Point2f>> checkerboardImageSpacePoints;
    process_images(path_to_directory, boardSize, checkerboardImageSpacePoints);

    vector<vector<Point3f>> worldSpaceCornerPoints(1);
    createKnownBoardPosition(boardSize, squareEdgeLength, worldSpaceCornerPoints[0]);
    worldSpaceCornerPoints.resize(checkerboardImageSpacePoints.size(), worldSpaceCornerPoints[0]);
    //rotation and translation vectors (rVectors, tVectors)
    vector<Mat> rVectors, tVectors;
    distortionCoefficients = Mat::zeros(8, 1, CV_64F);
    calibrateCamera(worldSpaceCornerPoints, checkerboardImageSpacePoints, boardSize, cameraMatrix,
                                 distortionCoefficients, rVectors, tVectors, CALIB_FIX_K5 + CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC);
    vector<float> perViewErrors;
    double rep_error = computeReprojectionErrors(worldSpaceCornerPoints, checkerboardImageSpacePoints, rVectors, tVectors, cameraMatrix,
            distortionCoefficients, perViewErrors, false);
    std::cout << "Reprojection Error: " << rep_error << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    Mat cameraMatrix, distortionCoefficient;
    Size chessboardDimensions = Size(6, 9);
    float calibrationSquareDimension = 0.03f;
    std::string path = "../chess_images";
    calibration_process(chessboardDimensions, calibrationSquareDimension, cameraMatrix,
                        distortionCoefficient, path);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you show images and detected chessboards?

Comment: @Micka how can I contact you?

Comment: you can upload to filehosting websites and link them here

Comment: @Micka Here are 36 pictures for calibration(coloured) and 34 grayscaled on which findChessboardCorners() returned true: https://www.4shared.com/folder/PSDaeTcI/opencv.html

Comment: @Micka Here also is code with calibration_results.txt where 1-2 rows are camera matrix size, 3-11 camera matrix values, 12-13 distortion matrix size, 14-18 distortion matrix values: https://github.com/markilebyak/opencv.git

Comment: you should use opencv's functions to draw the detected chessboard to check quality of the detections

Comment: @Micka I used drawChessboardCorners() from opencv

Comment: @Micka I posted here version without saving images with detect markers. I edited code here and edited code also on github I posted 2 messages before.

Comment: @Micka do you have any ideas?

Comment: I can only access the first page of your 4shared images. If you know that chessboard is correctly detected in all the images, you could try more or a subset. Try to get into the corners of the image. If possible, disable autofocus and use fixed focus only, although focus has, compared to zoom, minor impact on intrinsics.

Comment: @Micka I will try without focus, but what do you mean subset of images and what does it mean to get into corners?

Comment: the chessboard should cover the whole image as good as possible over all calibration positions. With subset I mean that maybe some images have bigger subpixel errors than others (the ones with pitched/rolled chessboard?) which could harm the optimization process.

Comment: did you do everything to make the pattern as planar als possible?

Comment: the pattern pictures look a bit blurred. Might be another issue => check subpixel chessboard detection

Comment: @Micka chessboard grid is lying on white ground which I am sure is horizontal. What I should do if subpixel error is bigger than other? Simply avoid it? And how I can know that it is bigger? And one more question, what do you mean pattern as planar as possible? Thank you for you help in advance)

Comment: e.g. if you have a sheet of paper, just lying on the ground, it's not perfectly planar. If ir isnt perfectly plsnar, your object positions have errors. Not sure how exact your object and pixel positions have to be for your desired calibration quality. In pitched/yawd camera orientations (relative to frontal chessboard) corner detection errors might have bigger impact, so do some experiments avoiding those images

Comment: @Micka thank you) In some time, I will tell you what I achieved.